# Error with uploading files from jupyter notebook to github

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook

When I view my dataframe in Jupyter notebook everything looks fine, but when I upload it to github, the dataframe looks odd.

I have already tried different encodings when I use pandas.read_csv()

Here is how the dataframe looks in github:

[image: Here is how the dataframe looks in github]

Comment: My guess is that Jupyter notebook has its own way of rendering the rawvalue, so it looks pretty. Whereas github is merely showing what is there.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the best way to deal with Jupyter notebooks is to clean the output before uploading to GitHub using something like [nbclean](https://github.com/choldgraf/nbclean)

And yes as per the comments @Joseph Seung Jae Dollar is correct, if you look in the pandas source code, there is some formatting / css stuff that is applied to prettify the dataframe ouput when it's being used in Jupyter

Short answer:

- clean notebooks before committing (mostly so you don't accidentally commit sensitive information)
- ignore the what it looks like in GitHub